# Preview how images scale on InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, images, resize

I used to be able to see "live" how an image was scaling when I was changing its size. Now in the CC version I only see the resulting size when I end the process. How can I change to the previous setting?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold down on the mouse after you have clicked for a second (wait until the coordinates box pops up, to be sure) before dragging to resize.

[image]

Comment: Yes! Excellent! Totally works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix!

You can fix this setting by clicking the InDesign drop-down menu, select "Preferences," then "Interface."

Under "Options," click on the "Live Screen Drawing," drop-down menu, and select "Immediate."

This allows immediate preview of scaling so you no longer need to click and hold.

Hope this helps!